# pseudo-element image not rendering on parent element :hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm attempting to add several images using pseudo-elements, when a parent list-item is hovered over. Upon inspecting in Chrome, the pseudo-element appears, but the .png isn't rendering properly. I'm wondering if I'm using the selectors properly or if there is another problem with the code. You can see a live example of this [here](https://preview.c9users.io/patbrennan/demo-project/launchschool/249/dictionary/dictionary.html?_c9_id=livepreview4&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io).

Here is the html:

```
<main>
  <section id="results">
    <ul>
      <li class="term-list">
        <dl>
          <dt class="term">hello</dt>
          <dd class="pronounce">[ <strong>he</strong>-lo ]</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li class="term-list">
        <dl>
          <dt class="term">word</dt>
          <dd class="pronounce">[ <strong>wurd</strong> ]</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li class="term-list">
        <dl>
          <dt class="term">another</dt>
          <dd class="pronounce">[ uh-<strong>nuth</strong>-er ]</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li class="term-list">
        <dl>
          <dt class="term">aviation</dt>
          <dd class="pronounce">[ ay-vee-<strong>ay</strong>-shun ]</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li class="term-list">
        <dl>
          <dt class="term">hello</dt>
          <dd class="pronounce">[ <strong>he</strong>-lo ]</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
.term-list {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.term-list:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.term-list:hover,
.term-list:hover + .term-list {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-transition: border-top .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-top .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: border-top .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-top .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-top .2s ease-in-out;
}

.term-list:hover {
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.term-list:hover::last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
}

.term-list:hover dl::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background: url("https://preview.c9users.io/patbrennan/demo-project/launchschool/249/dictionary/images/arrow-right.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

`background: url("https://preview.c9users.io/patbrennan/demo-project/launchschool/249/dictionary/images/arrow-right.png") 0 0 no-repeat;`

into

`background-image: url("https://preview.c9users.io/patbrennan/demo-project/launchschool/249/dictionary/images/arrow-right.png");`

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that specifying the position / repeat causes it not to render, even when `background-size` is specified?

Comment: It is not about the attributes in the rulese, it was more about the name itself: the `background-image` is a specific rule that allows you to specify the image url ONLY.
The `background` rule is a "shorthand" and it allows you to declare a list of rules, which have a specific order and composition. See this link for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

The answer below is only half correct.  `40px 40px` is valid.  The problem is that the shorthand property for `background` overrides the initially set `background-size`.  Overrides need to be placed after the shorthand property; otherwise, they get overridden.

## Original Answer

The reason is that your image is not 40px by 40px.

[image]

The image is properly being set, but you're only seeing the top left corner of it, which is transparent.  Use [`background-size: contain;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) on `.term-list:hover dl::after` to force it to be bound by the width and height of the pseudo-element.

Comment: Isn't using `background-size: 40px 40px;` the same thing? Your solution works - thank you! Just trying to understand why setting width/height & then the background-size manually isn't working. I've done this before, and it worked in other applications.

Comment: @patrickb You're right! My answer is wrong.  The real problem is that the `background-size` property is set before the `background` shorthand where you adjust the URL, positioning, repeat, **and size**.  The shorthand syntax is resetting the background size to `auto auto`. Terribly sorry for the incorrect information.